# Email integration

Tags: massemailmessage

I am looking for email integration for possibly sending out thousands of emails to contacts. I know salesforce doesn't want to be the outgoing email provider on that scale. Are there any options to integrate salesforce with on-premise corporate email server so I could use the corporate server for email blasts? We basically want to send feedback servey to our contacts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

ExactTarget has a wide variety of solutions. Here's a link to information on our Small Business offerings: http://www.exacttarget.com/clients/small-business.

This is really going to depend on the budget your organization has available and what your customer communication roadmap is. There are quite a few solutions for email, that's where many of those providers stop. ExactTarget is an enterprise-grade, cross-channel communication platform for B2B and B2C with a powerful marketing automation suite of tools to empower Marketers with the ability to create 1-to-1 relationships with their subscribers/customers.

With the use-case you've described (if that is ALL your organization wants to do), ExactTarget may be too much power. I'd have a decision maker from your business reach out to an ExactTarget sales rep to discuss viability. There may be a solution ExactTarget offers which will fit exactly (no pun intended) what your business needs.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out something like [ExactTarget](http://www.exacttarget.com/products/email-marketing/) which was recently acquired by SFDC and is part of their [Marketing Cloud](http://www.salesforce.com/marketing-cloud/overview/). There are [APIs for it](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.exacttarget.meta/exacttarget/node_4489.htm) too.  It can handle sending more emails.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few tools for this. If you are looking to do something very basic, you may just need a product like Mailchimp (which does have a Salesforce integration http://connect.mailchimp.com/integrations/salesforce). However, if you want to do something more complex, you'll likely need a marketing automation suite. The main ones with Salesforce integration would be:

- Pardot (which was purchased by ExactTarget and is now owned by Salesforce)
- Hubspot (good choice if you are not technically profecient)
- Marketo (similar to Eloqua)
- Eloqua (possibly the most technically demanding option - but likely the most powerful as well)

I have worked at companies that have used all three (and Mailchimp). The best choice would really depend on budget, technical chops/time to devote to training and what you are trying to accomplish.

Worth noting you may want to skip using your own corporate email server because at that volume (if something isn't carefully configured) you might end up getting your employee's emails blacklisted. One benefit of a service like say Hubspot is that they are taking that on themselves.